# counting the number of occurrences of a particular record in a database

Tags: sql

I have to count the number of occurrences of an entire record ( all fields matching) in a database.

For example, 
If I want to find the number of occurrences of the record `[ 1 5 10 30 45 25 60 20 35 55](i.e., 10 fields)` in a database table called StocksInventory. Say the database name is MultiProductInventory. How to proceed.

The answer to this i want to link for solving a problem on Artificial Bee Colony Optimization Problem.

Comment: please post some sample data and expected result  and explain along with it.

Comment: tag the relevant RDBMS you are using  and read this link on how to improve your question To get fast answers ..https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

Your query would look something like this but I suspect there is more to this. Please elaborate by providing sample Data and expected results.

```
select * from StocksInventory
WHERE 
FIELD1 = 1 AND
FIELD2 = 5 AND
FIELD3 = 10 AND
FIELD4 = 30 AND
FIELD5 = 45 AND
FIELD6 = 25 AND
FIELD7 = 60 AND
FIELD8 = 20 AND
FIELD9 = 35 AND
FIELD10 = 55
```